# ASP.NET MVC Javascript not firing the first time on page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

This should be really simple, but I can't get it to work - I'm trying to disable 2 drop down lists when a user clicks a checkbox.

```
@Html.DropDownList("StartTime", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{ Text="10:00 AM", Value = "10:00 AM" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text="12:00 PM", Value = "12:00 PM" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text="2:00 PM", Value = "2:00 PM" }
}

@Html.DropDownList("EndTime", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{ Text="10:00 AM", Value = "10:00 AM" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text="12:00 PM", Value = "12:00 PM" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text="2:00 PM", Value = "2:00 PM" }
}
@Html.CheckBox("chkAllDayEvent", new { @onclick = "AllDayEvent_Checked();" })

<script type='text/javascript'>

function AllDayEvent_Checked() {
    $("#chkAllDayEvent").click(function () {
        $('#EndTime').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
        $('#StartTime').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
}
</script>
```

My problem is that when I get to the page, the Javascript doesn't fire until I click the checkbox 3 times - on the 3rd time it disables the text boxes, then works as per normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have a function that assigns a click handler to a checkbox. You then trigger this function when the checkbox is clicked. So, when the checkbox is first clicked, you assign a click handler to that checkbox, rather than *firing the click handler*, which is what you want.

Try this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#chkAllDayEvent").click(function () {
        $('#EndTime').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
        $('#StartTime').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
</script>
```

```csh
@Html.CheckBox("chkAllDayEvent", new { @id = "chkAllDayEvent" })
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $("#chkAllDayEvent").click(function () {
        $('#EndTime').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
        $('#StartTime').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});

@Html.CheckBox("chkAllDayEvent", new { @id = "chkAllDayEvent" })
```

You don't need `AllDayEvent_Checked` function. as you are binding it using jquery.

Or

```
function AllDayEvent_Checked() {
        $('#EndTime').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
        $('#StartTime').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
}

@Html.CheckBox("chkAllDayEvent", new { "@onclick" = "AllDayEvent_Checked();" })
```

Comment: @Ant P, true, seen your answer after as soon as I answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Html.CheckBox("chkAllDayEvent", new {@onclick = "AllDayEvent_Checked();" })

function AllDayEvent_Checked() {    
    $('#EndTime').attr("disabled", $("#chkAllDayEvent").is(':checked'));
    $('#StartTime').attr("disabled", $("#chkAllDayEvent").is(':checked'));

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the "@onclick" gives an error - it shouldn't need to be in quotes.  Also, @onclick = "blah" works ok as the onclick event is being rendered in the view, just doesn't seem to work for the first few clicks on the checkox

Answer (score 0):

```
function AllDayEvent_Checked() {
    $('#EndTime').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
    $('#StartTime').attr("disabled", $(this).is(':checked'));
}

@Html.CheckBox("chkAllDayEvent", new { "@onclick" = "AllDayEvent_Checked();" })
```